# How to choice specific data value by row or column index in SAS?

Tags: r, sas

I usually use R, but I just start studying SAS.

In R, we can make some data.frame like this :

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1:6),nrow=2,ncol=3))
```

and then

```
df[1,2]
```

is 3.

Here is my question. How can I use row and column index in SAS?
I coudln't find this..

I want to use row and column number by index of double loop

Comment: Why would you WANT to reference values by either their 'row' or their 'col'?  Perhaps you have not structured your dataset properly?  What is it that you are actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to use row or col number by index of loop.

Comment: What is your overall end goal of your loop? Recall that SAS is inherently a looping language. A `set` statement in a data step will loop through every row automatically. You certainly can reference the intersection of rows and columns in SAS, but it's generally not used unless you're doing things in IML, OR, or CASL.

Comment: You are asking how to do a very specific thing but have not provide any overview of why you want to do that.  This sounds like an https://xyproblem.info/ Provide a realistic example of a use case where you think this technique would be useful.  You will get a solution that you can then learn to use for similar problems.

Comment: SAS processes data differently and trying to use the same approach from R in SAS will not work. You have to learn how SAS works first and the implicit loop within a data step means that double loops are rare. Usually you would need just an array most likely for whatever you're doing. If you're doing absolute basic matrix work, then IML is likely your best bet but if you're new to SAS it's unlikely that's the right answer. I program in both R and SAS and they're different. Tidyverse is closer to SAS in terms of mental workflow.

Comment: Aside, in R you want to avoid row/col index looping for vectorized operations. All `base` objects in R is an extension of the vector (i.e., matrix/array/data frame a bind or list of equal-length atomic vectors). In fact, there is no scalar value in R just a vector of one element and one dimension!

Comment: There are many usecases for this question, kinda a disgrace it's so hard to do in SAS. E.g. when your IT team provides you with variable/column names that change all the time (e.g. depending on date), but you know you always need column 10 and 11. The easiest thing to do is use index 10 and 11.

Answer (score 1):

If the row number and column number have meaning then you probably do not want to store your "matrix" in that form.  Instead you probably want to store it in a tall format where the row and column values are stored in variables and the values of the cells in your matrix are stored in another variable.  Since you didnt' provide any meaning to your example let's just name these variables ROW, COL and VALUE.

```
data have;
  do col=1 to 3 ;
    do row=1 to 2 ;
       value+1;
       output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Now if you want to find the value when ROW=1 and COL=2 it is a simple WHERE condition.

```
proc print data=have;
  where row=1 and col=2;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs    col    row    value

 3      2      1       3
```

In a real dataset the ROW might be the individual case or person ID and the COL might be the YEAR or VISIT_NUMBER or SAMPLE_NUMBER of the value.

Answer (score 0):

You access columns via names and rows via `_n_` if you really need but there isn't a good usage for this type of logic.

For example, if you wanted the third row and second variable from the SASHELP CLASS data set.

Note that you need to know the name of the variable, you cannot rely on the index/position.

This displays the information:

```
proc print data=sashelp.class(firstobs = 2 obs=2);
var Age;
run;
```

This puts in a data set, two different ways:

```
data want;
  set sashelp.class (firstobs = 2 obs=2);
  keep age;
run;

data want;
  set sashelp.class ;
  if _n_ = 3; *filters only the third row into the data set;
run;
```

R & Python import all data into memory and use that method as the default processing method. SAS instead only loads one row at a time and then continues to loop through each row within a data step, so you have to think of each step differently. Basically break your processes into smaller steps and they work. SAS does have some really nice built in functionality, like confidence intervals by default or the ability to aggregate data at multiple levels within a single procedure.